# When using "voice typing", how can I capitalize a proper noun?

Tags: voice-recognition

When I press the speech-to-text button on my keyboard, I can dictate some text. Say I have a pub called the Red Lion that I want to mention. How can I get it to type "Red Lion" instead of "red lion"?

Letting it enter "red lion" and going back and editing it with a normal keyboard is very slow, because the popup menu of alternative transcriptions makes each edit take an extra click.

Comment: Related to this is: How to make voice typing use punctuation.

Comment: @ScottSeverance That's easy: you just name the punctuation mark you want to type. It insists on calling a full stop "period", and only works for the most common punctuation marks, but it's fine for short messages.

Comment: As of 2019 this still doesn't work reliably for me, either for punctuation or capitalization. Wish there was a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Picked up from [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66285/what-is-the-list-of-commands-to-dictate-punctuation-capitalization-and-line-bre) Ruben Roy answer in a more recent question:

You can use this comments to start and stop typing with capitals with the Google voice typing Android keyboard.

```
"Caps <word>"                           Type with an initial capital
"All Caps <word>"                       Type in all uppercase
"Caps On"                               Start typing words with initial capitals
"Caps Off"                              Stop typing words with initial capitals
```

Comment: Your first link is not for the Android version of voice recognition. Notice the keyboard command references.

Comment: hit or miss m afraid
Google voice to text is most likely to type the words "capitalise" rather than take the instruction

Comment: @freda Nobody even mentioned the word "capitalise", so there's no point complaining that it doesn't work.

Comment: None of these are currently working using google keyboard.