# What is the list of commands to dictate punctuation, capitalization and line breaks?

Tags: voice-recognition

I'm on a Sprint Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.3.

I would love to become a power user of the dictation feature to dictate text messages and emails. More often than not, however, I have to hand-edit the dictated text not because of text comprehension issues but because of punctuation, capitalization and spacing problems.

These are the "commands" I've found to work. What is the full list?

```
"period"     --> .   (works fairly reliably)
"comma"      --> ,   (works fairly reliably)
"new line"   --> \n  (works about 50% of the time)
```

I've not gotten `capital` or anything like that to work, or acronyms. If you know how it works, please share.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Commands**

```
"New Line" or "Next Line"               Press the enter key once, capitalize next word
"New Paragraph" or "Next Paragraph"     Press the enter key twice, capitalize next word
"Caps <word>"                           Type with an initial capital
"All Caps <word>"                       Type in all uppercase
"Caps On"                               Start typing words with initial capitals
"Caps Off"                              Stop typing words with initial capitals
```

**Punctuations**

```
&                                       "ampersand" or "and sign" 
.                                       "period" or "dot"
:                                       "colon"     
?                                       "question mark"
!                                       "exclamation point"     
,                                       "comma"
=                                       "equal sign"    
@                                       "at sign"
/                                       "forward slash" or "slash"  
-                                       "hyphen"
'                                       "begin single quote" or "open single quote"     
'                                       "end single quote" or "close single quote"
"                                       "begin quote" or "open quote"   
"                                       "close quote" or "end quote"
(                                       "left parenthesis" or "open parenthesis"    
)                                       "right parenthesis" or "close parenthesis"
%                                       "percent sign"
$                                        "dollar sign"
#                                       "pound sign"    
°                                       "degree sign"
:-)                                     "smiley face"
:-(                                     "sad face"
```

Comment: I'm guessing trial and error. Not all of these still work (on my KitKat device).

Comment: "Full stop" also works for me for `.`, at least in UK English.

Comment: I had to view this on the Web because it was screwed up in the Android app. Also, the quote commands don't work on my S3.

Comment: Most of these punctuations don't work for me on Marshmallow and a Nexus 6P. As in virtually nothing after 'comma.' Slash works on occasion, but annoyingly adds a space before and/or after the slash. Everything else is a fail.

Comment: Doesn't work offline. Why?

Comment: Almost none of these work for me after comma, except the smiley and sad faces. Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 7.0.

Answer (score 0):

Some more voice commands, from http://thedroidlawyer.com/2015/09/punctuation-commands-for-dictation-in-voice-to-text-for-android/:

```
Dash = dash (-)
Ellipsis or dot dot dot = ellipsis (…)
Asterisk = asterisk (*)
Backslash = backslash (\)
Open bracket = open bracket ([)
Close bracket = closed bracket (])
```

More:

```
!    "exclamation mark"
```