# Why don't the capitalization voice commands work in the Google app?

Tags: google

The capitalization, quotation marks, and some punctuation marks don't work for me In the Google app.

Is there some additional software I should know about?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try these related questions: [What is the list of commands to dictate punctuation, capitalization and line breaks?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/66285/what-is-the-list-of-commands-to-dictate-punctuation-capitalization-and-line-bre), & [When using “voice typing”, how can I capitalize a proper noun?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/58082/when-using-voice-typing-how-can-i-capitalize-a-proper-noun)